# How does event.shiftKey affects the output result from an input form?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have an input form and it confuses me how the `shiftKey` event exactly works in this occasion.

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="return event.shiftKey;">
```

I have tested it on my computer but I couldn't figure out what the code above does.
Can somebody please explain it to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it tells that its key pressed with <kbd>shiftKey</kbd> or not.

if `event.shiftKey` returns true means **"The shift key was pressed!"**
else **"The shift key was NOT pressed!"**

**If you press with SHIFT Key then only the text will be typed on the input box.**

[check this fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/FU722/)

Comment: you mean that it will be displayed in textbox?

Comment: @Molnia it will allow only keywords which are pressed with `Shift Key`, like shift+s

Comment: @Molnia yes, the input in the textbox will be shown only if the shift key is pressed.

Comment: The fiddle link was really delighting. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The shiftKey event attribute returns a Boolean value that indicates whether or not the "SHIFT" key was pressed when an event was triggered.

If you press SHIFT Key and Type any Text it will fill Text Because it is True otherwise it is false so text not entered.

Comment: So the input in the textbox will be shown only if the shift key is pressed right?

Answer (score 0):

Now you are unable to write anything in this input .

you will be  only able to write if you press shift key along with.